# making Linq sum better

Tags: c#, linq

I want to find all the `physical` card effects from the
`List<CardEffect> opponenteffect`

This codeblock is what i came up with

```
    int netPhysicalDamage = oponenteffect.FindAll(
        ce => ce.type == CardEffect.Type.physical
        ).Sum(ce => ce.amount);
```

Is possible to make this to single Linq function call?

---

I want to find all the `physical` card effects from the
`List<CardEffect> opponenteffect`

This codeblock is what i came up with

```
    int netPhysicalDamage = oponenteffect.FindAll(
        ce => ce.type == CardEffect.Type.physical
        ).Sum(ce => ce.amount);
```

Edit: "Single Linq function call" was not a good idea to make this better

Edit2: The question was not very good. I was unfamiliar with `linq` and I thought was doing  something wrong with this part of code. Thanks for you attention.

Comment: Why is it important to be a "single" LINQ call?

Comment: `FindAll` isn't a LINQ method, use `Where` instead.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Actually he said "better", not more important...

Comment: @musefan - There's no reference to "better" in his question. He's just asked if it is possible to make this a single LINQ function call. I'm asking why that is important.

Comment: @Agramer,OP wants to explain his question with example of FindAll

Comment: @Enigmativity You've got a point there, I agree that  "single call" is not "better".

Comment: @User_PWY So what do you mean by "better" in that case? The code you have now is simple, concise and does exactly what you want.

Comment: @DavidG - Who are you asking? Please use the `@` notification system.

Comment: @Enigmativity OP, that's why I didn't use @

Comment: @Enigmativity: Perhaps I'll put a feature request in meta, see if they can somehow make the title stand out more... perhaps they could make the font slightly larger than the other text...

Comment: @DavidG The question itself was not good. (Made edit 2), and also requested flag "should be closed because ambiguous question"

Comment: @vahidkargar He changed the question. He specifically asked for a LINQ query.

Comment: @User_PWY - Please don't edit your question to change the validity of the comments and/or questions.

Answer (score 7):

The conditional [operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) is your friend in this case:

```
int result = oponenteffect.Sum(ce => ce.type == CardEffect.Type.physical ? ce.amount : 0);
```

Comment: Worth noting that this could get a little dangerous if `Sum` is swapped with `Average`.

Comment: @DavidG and now in my defence: well, we can agree in the quality of the question, but it was crystal clear: _Is possible to make this to single Linq function call?_ ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should really be using a `Where` *and* a `Sum`. So you should do this:

```
int netPhysicalDamage = oponenteffect.Where(
    ce => ce.type == CardEffect.Type.physical
    ).Sum(ce => ce.amount);
```

To make my answer 'valid' for your question (because that's what SO voters will pick up on), I am assuming that by "single call" you actually mean it will only process the query once. In this case it will, as `Where` returns an `IEnumerable` and doesn't execute until the result is required by a subsequent call. So in this case `Sum` is the only 'call'.

Also, you edited your question to suggest you do not require it to be a single function anyway.

Comment: It's not an `IQueryable` -  it's a `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @Enigmativity: That's what I said

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at this code:

```
var ams = 0.0;
var bms = 0.0;
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var a = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000).Where(x => x % 2 == 0).Sum();
    sw.Stop();
    ams += sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
    sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var b = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000).Sum(x => x % 2 == 0 ? x : 0);
    sw.Stop();
    bms += sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
};
Console.WriteLine(ams);
Console.WriteLine(bms);
```

The results I get are similar to this:

```
853.603399999998
1268.61419999997
```

This means that two separate LINQ calls are "better" than a single `.Sum(...)` call.